# Does Google Cloud Vision contain (the possibility of) post-OCR text correction?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, google-cloud-vision

I am searching for the answer on this question on the internet, but can't find it. 
I mean something like auto-correction, or no correction but suggestions for more obvious words. Is this feature part of Google cloud vision, or should i use an external program for this?

I know that Google cloud vision also tells you something about the likeliness of discussing a certain topic (medical, violence, etc). Doe it has a built-in feature that automatically uses a 'medical dictionary' when analyzing a medical document? For example, when the word 'miniscule' is being found in an medical text, does it change (or propose to change) it to 'meniscus'? So is domain specific knowledge being used?

And does anybody know how about for Microsoft Cognitive Services?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Vision, the type of Suggestions you are asking for are not currently supported, so you’ll need an external program to achieve it (I’m not aware of any).

Since you are extracting text from an image, you’ll get the word that is most likely to actually be written in the text (according to the API’s predictive model) and not the word that would make more sense according to the topic. In the [API response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#text_detection_responses), you’ll also get a confidence score for the transcription, but for this particular [feature](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature) (DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION), additional results (alternatives) are not supported yet.